# MS Project 2013: Export Single Page & Notes

Tags: ms-project

How can I do following in MS Project 2013:

1. Gantt Chart export task along with dates in different page. Wish I could export Gantt chart along with dates so could see them in single page.
2. Can I add Timeline (Start..End Dates) to export?
3. I have added notes to tasks. How can I export them along with Gantt Chart?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "different pages" and by exporting? I think your question needs to be a bit more clear.
If it is exporting to Excel that you mean then I can suggest the following:

1) Arrange your Gantt-chart view: make sure the desired columns are in place. Remove the ones you are not interested in

2) Execute Ctrl+A or click on the little blank square on the top left of your Gantt-chart (just like how you select all cells in Excel) --> this should select all your tasks

3) On the Ribbon: click Task (if I remember correctly), then click on Outline, so that it expands all indented tasks. Repeat this a few more times (MSP does not expand all indented tasks on all levels immediately)

4) Copy paste the selection to Excel. Depending on the time formatting it is quite possible that you'llneed to convert the copy pasted Start and Finish dates cells in Excel by using the DATEVALUE() function

Despite this being a non-automatic way we tend to use this at times. It does depend on how frequent you need to do this. Based on the frequency and on the type of output you like, it could be a better idea to think about reporting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I meant by if you export gantt to PDF, calendar goes to next page(s). Can I have everything on single page (pdf)? Just easy readability stand-point. am not looking export to excel option.